# Create an item in a custom list overwriting the item

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom-list, copy-item

I'm working on a list that under a certain condition, copies to another list using the "create item" command.

It's for student marks.  So when the grades get put in, the list fires and copies to a watch list for grades lower than 50.  It works fine.

So let's say a month goes by and another grade gets put in the first list, and that mark is also below 50.  Is there a way to just copy the new mark into the second list.

Answer (score 0):

You can first check the second list has the data. If the item exists then do Update List Item Action. Else use Create Item.

Comment: Thanks Amal, What's the command to check if it exists?  And if it does exist will it only update the changes?

Answer (score 0):

Continuing with the above answer from Amal, To check wehter item exists, use SPD Workflow HTTP Web Service Call and REST API to get the item from List B

I hope your lists are in the below schema

**LIST A**

```
ID     |    Student      |       Mark
--------------------------------------------
1      |    Student X    |       40
2      |    Student Y    |       55
3      |    Student Z    |       49
```

**LIST B**

```
Student      |       Mark
-----------------------------
Student X    |       40
Student Z    |       49
```

Endpoint URI: `<site url>/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('<List Name>')/items?$filter=(Student eq 'Student X')"`

Refer below for more information

[CALLING THE SHAREPOINT 2013 REST API FROM A SHAREPOINT DESIGNER WORKFLOW](https://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2013/04/09/calling-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api-from-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/)

Answer (score 0):

Additionally you can use CAML query to check the existence of the items in the list, so if it exist then update else insert. but how exactly you are adding or updating the list, i.e event receiver, workflow, or jquery